# I just get System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I've been tried to do an algorithm that ask for a sentence and put the words backwards, for example if I insert "Cookies and milk" it would give back "milk and Cookies", but it gives me System.IndexOutOfRangeException in the second for. Please help

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sentence;
            string spac = " ";
            char[] phr;

            char space = char.Parse(spac);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Write a sentence");
            sentence = Console.ReadLine();

            phr = sentence.ToCharArray();


            for (int i = phr.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (phr[i] == space)
                {
                    for (int j = i++; phr[j] != phr.Length-1 || phr[j]!=space; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(phr[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            

            
          


        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: Did u use the debugger to see what index you are accessing of the array and whether that is valid?

Comment: Don't use `i++` in your inner loop. The first time through, j will be set to phr.Length, which is out of range. You also shouldn't compare phr[j] to the length. Compare j directly.

Comment: My crystal ball suggest that `j` is equal to `phr.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string into an array based on any character.  If you split by space you can keep the words intact.  Do this, then reverse the order, and join it again.

```
string sentence = "Cookies and Milk";

string wordsReversed = 
    string.Join(" ",
        sentence.Split(' ').Reverse()
    );

Console.WriteLine(wordsReversed); // "Milk and Cookies"
```